# Periodic solution of first order ODE

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

There is a famous result shows that for every continuous function $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$, the first order autonomous system 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{x}=f(x), \\
x(t_0)=x_0,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for any $t_0, x_0\in{\mathbb R}$, the system above does not have any periodic solution. Now, the question is that under what condition a first order non-autonomous system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{x}=f(t,x), \\
x(t_0)=x_0,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for appropriate $f$ and $t_0, x_0\in{\mathbb R}$ has no periodic solution.

The special case interesting for me is for
$$
f(t,x) = \frac{-x+1+\cos t}{\Delta -x\sin t },
$$
where $\Delta$ is a positive constant less than maximum of $(1+\cos t)\sin t$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$, $t_0 = -\pi$ and $x_0=0$.

Any idea or any method applied to similar problem (with reference), is appreciated.

Comment: What do numerical calculations suggest? If you have not done those, I suggest you put this question on hold until you have.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Numerical simulations using ode45 and ode23s admits on nonexistence for the case I am working on. FYI, I am working to prove that a system which I am working on has a saddle-node-invariant-circle bifurcation, so in part of it I wanna show that a node is globally absorbing. The problem is reduced to the problem introduced above. Proving this, the proof of claim is completed and I can publish it. The origin of problem is mathematical neuroscience in which a system of two neurons modeled as a 4-dimensional dynamical system.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. Thank you all for your interest.